# Order query by id

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on the following query:

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM user_uploads WHERE id_user = '.$id_user;
```

I would like to order it with: ORDER BY upload_id DESC - but I'm stuck on how do this, or where to put the code in this particullar case.

Can somebody help me please? 
Thanks

Comment: honestly... you can't even google for some docs on what is core SQL syntax?

Comment: All you had to do is google `mysql order by desc`. It would have taken longer to write this question that a simple search.

Comment: thanks guys! I knew it was something very simple. i have tried to google for the answer but just couldn't find it at that time :) thanks again for yor answers

Answer (score 1):

Just do :

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM user_uploads WHERE id_user = '.$id_user.' ORDER BY upload_id DESC';
```

Comment: thank you very much :) I am new to programming but willing to learn

Answer (score 0):

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM user_uploads WHERE id_user = '.$id_user.' ORDER BY upload_id DESC;
```

Comment: thanks :) I am new to programming but willing to learn

Answer (score 0):

While you could do

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM user_uploads WHERE id_user = $id_user ORDER BY upload_id DESC";
```

you should definitly look into parameterized queries. Google for PDO!

Comment: thanks :) I am new to programming but willing to learn